# ArcGIS Surface Volume - multiple results in one table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, volume, surface, error-000725

I'm calculating volumes and surfaces using Surface Volume tool. According to the help page:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/surface-volume.htm

it should be possible to obtain results from multiple runs in one .txt file (one calculation -> one row), by specifying the existing .txt as the output in following calculations. However it doesn't seem to work for me, since I get an "ERROR 000725 - output file already exists" (on the second operation). I need to do long series of calculations with varying heights, thus having the results in one table at once would be immensely helpful.

Maybe I'm missing something here, but it seems pretty straightforward to me. Or could the help page be wrong about this? I use ArcGIS 10.4.1 Advanced.

Comment: Is the file open?  It may not be able to append if it becomes read-only?

Comment: I have complete volume calculations in Drone2Map and looking for a similar tool in ArcGIS Pro. Help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to an ArcGIS Toolbox Tool that will loop the Surface Model Tool and write the outputs to a text file.
https://github.com/gerry1138/ArcGIS-Loop-Surface-Volumes